# Remove Values on Rangeslider (HTML/CSS/Jquery)

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am currently working on a Character Creator for a GTA Project. Therefore I am using the Hair IDs provided by the game and some Addon Hairs. Problem is (for Male Chars as an Example) :

- GTA IDs go from: 0-74
- Addon IDs Start at 75

Would be great actually, if there wasn't the problem that the GTA Hairstyles actually only go from 0-37 and repeat themselves from 38-74, as you can see [here](https://wiki.rage.mp/index.php?title=Male_Hair_Styles). So in my character creator I would have the GTA Hairstyles twice before the user gets to the Addon Hairtyles (A no go as the user might think that at the end there wont be anything else so they dont even bother going so far)
I found a solution where I could, when the user gets to 37, make him jump to 75 afterwards. (Usability wise this is quite strange as the slider would jump almost half of the bar to the right, so that the user might think that there is a bug where he cant see all the values)

So now my question :
Is it possible to exclude values on a range slider and append new ones at the end? So that I would have such a slider:  0-34/removed values/75-96.
Or do you have a different idea on how to solve such a setup in a character creator. The Char Creator is created using HTML/CSS & Javascript/Jquery

Comment: What do you have so far? Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: So far I have my slider setup using <input type="range" id="hairstyle" min="0" max="96" /> 
And from that slider I want to remove values from 35-74.
As I stated, I tried something I found on google, where the values arent actually removed from the slider but they are skipped, so that they are still part of the slider which is strange usability wise.

Comment: Do you want it to jump from 33 to 75, like a literal gap in the middle of the slider that the user can see visually but cannot use or make it seamless (the next tick after 33 is 75, and user has no idea that it is going on).

Comment: Again more code would be helpful. What do you have in your js?